# Unusual amount of pageviews in GA4 - result of headless web?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, headless

I manage the analytics of a website that uses a headless web, and have noticed an unusual amount of  page_view events one some of the pages.

Perhaps it could have something to do with the website being headless, meaning that the URL doesn't change/refresh when clicking, even though the content on the site is changed as if it was a url redirect.

does this make sense? Anyone got any good suggestions on why my events might be off?

My first thought was that the event tracking configuration wasn't set up correctly, resulting in multiple pageviews on the wrong pages (i.e. first page visit → 2nd page → 3rd page = three pageview fires on first page), but upon investigation this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Checked for bot traffic and it doesn't seem to be that, as we're also tracking through UA and Matomo and those numbers look way more likely.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you've described is not necessarily a headless website, it's just a misconfigured Single Page Application that doesn't care about updating the url. A Huge SEO issue, but not a blocker for Analytics. And when an SPA affects analytics, it's most commonly less events, not more.

If the bot traffic inflates one analytics system as a side-effect of whatever it does, it will inflate similarly pretty much any other analytics system, so if numbers in UA and Matomo look alike, it doesn't rule out bots. Especially if your GTM sends events to both systems on the same triggers.

Now, there are ways to debug it besides just going to the website and looking at a few pages tracking.

In cases like this, you want to use data to debug your tracking.

You build a report (custom report, or just use pregenerated UA reports) in which you compare the anomalous traffic period to the previous period so that you would have your base. Now, whatever dimension you're using, you're looking at the value or a few values of this dimension that contain most of the anomalous traffic. This is to see if any dimension contains the outlier that would explain the nature of the anomaly.

Dimensions that I would look at right away are: hostname, country, hour of the day, source, page, landing page, exit page, referrer. I would also take a quick look at all the conversion numbers, bounce rate and avg time on site.

If all of these look organic, then I would presume natural growth of good traffic.

Comment: Thanks for replying! 

I did check for bot traffic prior to posting, and we feel like we can rule that out. UA and Matomo have one set of numbers, only GA4 delivers wild numbers, which is why I looked into event configurations etc.

 Even though my description of the headless web might be lacking, it is bulit as a headless web (checked with devs), do you think this could affect it at all?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You're using GTM to deploy Matomo, GA UA and GA4? You're also not supposed to look at GA4's pre-generated reports. They are severely bugged. Either use the explorer (it has a tendency to bug out as well), or export the data to BQ and look at it through SQL

Comment: Big thanks! We don't use GTM for Matomo. Good to know about the GA4 reports tab, I'll avoid that in the future. I'll try exporting too. Thanks again!